# Use ADK or AIK to deploy windows 7?

Tags: sccm

I'm Configuring my new SCCM 2016 server and I'm confused about the requirements for deploying windows 7. Most of the PCs in the company are using windows 7 but a few windows 10. I want to be able to deploy windows 7 and windows 10 to my systems. I want to know if I install ADK for windows 10, Can I use it to deploy windows 7 also? Or I need to install AIK for 7? Can I install both of alongside? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SCCM 2016 requirements regarding ADK can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/osd/plan-design/infrastructure-requirements-for-operating-system-deployment

With ADK 10 you can deploy Windows 7 as well as Windows 10. If you need a boot image from AIK, you can import it inside the SCCM application, but will not be customizable by it (you can customize it yourself; SCCM will just inject the OSD Engine at the time of Updating Distribution Points for it).